# Getting SpooleFileList of a user in java with all the operations which we can do in as400(like view,change..etc)

Tags: java, ibm-midrange

I want output in the following format, which we get in as400 when WRKSPLF is executed

[image: As400 ScreenShot]

I am using the following code for retrieving the information from as400

```
         try
            {
                AS400 as400System = new AS400();
                String strSpooledFileName;

                SpooledFileList splfList = new SpooledFileList(as400System);

                splfList.openAsynchronously();

                splfList.waitForListToComplete();

                Enumeration enume= splfList.getObjects();
                ArrayList<SpoolVO> list = new ArrayList<SpoolVO>();

                while( enume.hasMoreElements() )
                {
                    SpoolVO splVO = new SpoolVO();
                    SpooledFile splf = (SpooledFile)enume.nextElement();
                    if (splf != null)
                    {
                        // output this spooled file's name
                        splVO.setFileName(splf.getStringAttribute(SpooledFile.ATTR_SPOOLFILE));
                        splVO.setUserName(splf.getStringAttribute(SpooledFile.ATTR_JOBUSER));
                        splVO.setUserData(splf.getStringAttribute(SpooledFile.ATTR_USERDATA));
                        splVO.setDevice(splf.getStringAttribute(SpooledFile.ATTR_OUTPUT_QUEUE));
                        splVO.setTotalPages(splf.getIntegerAttribute(SpooledFile.ATTR_PAGES));
                        splVO.setCurrentPage(splf.getIntegerAttribute(SpooledFile.ATTR_CURPAGE));
                        splVO.setCopy(splf.getIntegerAttribute(SpooledFile.ATTR_COPIES));

                        list.add(splVO);
                    }
                }
          splfList.close();
```

Now by using the above code I am able to get all the fields except the Options(Opt). I want Options field in java which enables me to do all the operations like send, change, hold, etc. as specified in screenshot.

Is this possible doing with java??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How? Well, you start writing Java programs that perform all the options. It's not at all clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing that you are using [JT400](http://jt400.sourceforge.net/) you would use [SpooledFileList](http://javadoc.midrange.com/jtopen/com/ibm/as400/access/SpooledFileList.html) and [SpooledFile](http://javadoc.midrange.com/jtopen/com/ibm/as400/access/SpooledFile.html) to get the details you want.  Edit your question to explain the specific details you want to retrieve.  Post the code you tried.

**Edit:**

The Options field is not an attribute of a spooled file; you can't retrieve it from anywhere.  It is a field on the display panel that lets the user request an action to be performed by the WRKSPLF command.  You will need to provide that functionality within your Java program.  For example, if your end user types a 3, you would issue the HLDSPLF command.  If she types a 6, you would issue the RLSSPLF command.

Comment: I have modified the question. Could you please check it and reply for that. Thanks in advance.